# Get parent of object instantiated by DataTemplate

Tags: c#, listview, uwp-xaml

I have ListView with UserControl in its DataTemplate:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyCollection}" x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyUserControl Loaded="OnLoaded" Content="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I try to get the parent ListView in MyUserControl's code behind (by different ways):

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent1 = Parent;
    var parent2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
    var parent3 = FindName("MyListView");
    var parent4 = DataContext;
}
```

parent1 is null,
parent2 is ListViewItemPresenter,
parent3 is null too,
parent4 is my ViewModel class (where MyCollection lies).

How do I get the actual ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these `VisualTreeExtensions` From [UWPCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/VisualTreeExtensions.cs)

For Getting parent `ListView` from `ListView.ItemTemplate` (`DataTemplate`) use `FindVisualAscendant` method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find first ascendant control of a specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to search for.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="element">Child element.</param>
    /// <returns>Ascendant control or null if not found.</returns>
    public static T FindAscendant<T>(this FrameworkElement element)
        where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        if (element.Parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (element.Parent is T)
        {
            return element.Parent as T;
        }

        return (element.Parent as FrameworkElement).FindAscendant<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find first visual ascendant control of a specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type to search for.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="element">Child element.</param>
    /// <returns>Ascendant control or null if not found.</returns>
    public static T FindVisualAscendant<T>(this FrameworkElement element)
        where T : FrameworkElement
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (parent is T)
        {
            return parent as T;
        }

        return (parent as FrameworkElement).FindVisualAscendant<T>();
    }
```